# How to scrape phone numbers using "skype_c2c_container" with Scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, phone-number

I am trying to scrape the text following the span named "skype_c2c_container" or "skype_c2c_container notranslate" (actually the phone number published in a website).

For instance in this website: http://adcamfabrications.co.uk/ 
or in this one: http://aandbairsystems.co.uk/

I know how to extract ALL the text in the website, and then could probably use a pattern recognition of phone numbers, but I am sure there is an easier way. I manged to extract text by meta name or div id or div name but couldn't manage to figure how to do the same for span names containing specific words (e.g. "skype").

examples of one of the codes I tried:

```
 item["phone_number"] =response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "Skype")] | //span[contains(@class, "skype")]').extract()
```

or:

```
item["phone_number"] =response.xpath("//span[(@skype_c2c_container)]").extract()
```

example of what I am trying to extract:

```
<span class="skype_c2c_text_span">+44 (0) 1234 1234</span>
```

and I would like to get back the text:
"+44 (0) 1234 1234"

Answer (score 2):

Locate the element with `Tel` text and get the *following text sibling*:

```
$ scrapy shell http://adcamfabrications.co.uk/
In [1]: response.xpath("//span[. = 'Tel']/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
Out[1]: u'+44 (0) 1889 571690'
```

For the second web-site:

```
$ scrapy shell http://aandbairsystems.co.uk/
In [1]: response.xpath("//td[@class='phonenumber']/text()").re(r"24 Hour cover Tel : (\d+ \d+)")[0]
Out[1]: u'01978 661999'
```

Comment: Thanks, it definitely worked for the first website but didn't work for the second. In addition it created another problem - the scraper didn't return any data from the 2nd website (I am extracting more data from the website but it didn't return anything this time stating: "SyntaxWarning: name 'var_name' is assigned to before global declaration"). any idea what might have happened?

Comment: @Angie sure it would not work for any website out there. Updated the answer, check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I now understand better your approach though I am looking for a more systematic way, if available out there. I want to try and capture all the text of a span from a specific class. In addition - how can I overcome these errors in order to proceed with a blank item rather than not scraping any data from that website? many many thanks

Comment: @Angie okay, put it into a try/except and return an empty item field in case of an error.